# Why can't the compiler convert to bool implicitly from sp<android::MetaData>?

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk, stagefright

I am trying to compile ffmpeg with libstagefright using NDK. I am getting the following error on the compilation of libstagefright.cpp:

```
libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp: In function 'int Stagefright_init(AVCodecContext*)':
libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp:283:9: error: no match for 'operator!' (operand type is 'android::sp<android::MetaData>')
 if (!meta) {
     ^
libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp:283:9: note: candidate is:
libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp:283:9: note: operator!(bool) <built-in>
libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp:283:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'android::sp<android::MetaData>' to 'bool'
make: *** [libavcodec/libstagefright.o] Error 1
```

The code for the relevant section of libstagefright.cpp is:

```
meta = new MetaData;
    if (!meta) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto fail;
    }
    meta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
    meta->setInt32(kKeyWidth, avctx->width);
    meta->setInt32(kKeyHeight, avctx->height);
    meta->setData(kKeyAVCC, kTypeAVCC, avctx->extradata, avctx->extradata_size);
```

I am using  `NDK r10e-rc4 (64-bit)` and `Ubuntu 14 64 bit`

Can somebody please guide as to why this error is occurring, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for compiler to write code for

```
if (!meta)
```

`android::sp` class has to either have `operator!()` defined, or there has to be a way for this class to be converted to bool, i.e. `operator bool()`. Since you can't change `android::sp` implementation, you'll need to find another way to write that. I assume this should work:

```
if (meta != NULL)
```

Comment: But libstagefright.cpp is written by professional developers. Surely there must be another way to compile it other than making changes to it. It should work as is. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe it was written with different version of android ndk? Though I would assume android ndk wouldn't introduce non-backward compatible changes for ideological reasons...

Comment: On changing it to `if (meta != NULL)`, that error dissappeared but a host of other "undefined reference to ..." errors appeared. I assume that there is some sort of linking problem. Maybe the lib files are not being linked correctly.

Anyways, Thank you for your response.